# WinHTTP Error 12029 Cannot Connect

Tags: c++, windows, connection, winhttp

I am trying to make an http connection to my own domain and return a string. I have it working with www.microsoft.com but when i change the domain to www.atomic-gaming.info (my domain) i get an error 12029 and if i change the link to www.yahoo.com i get an error 12017

code

```
 DWORD dwSize = 0;
 DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
 LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
 BOOL bResults = FALSE;
 HINTERNET hSession = NULL,  
 hConnect = NULL,
 hRequest = NULL;

 // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
 hSession = WinHttpOpen( L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",  
 WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
 WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,  
 WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );
 WinHttpSetOption(hSession, WINHTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT_POLICY_ALWAYS,NULL,NULL);
 // Specify an HTTP server.
 if( hSession )
 hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"www.microsoft.com",
 INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0 );

 // Create an HTTP request handle.
 if( hConnect )
 hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", NULL,
 NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,  
 WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,  
 WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE );

 // Send a request.
 if( hRequest )
 bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
 WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
 WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,  
 0, 0 );


 // End the request.
 if( bResults )
 bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );

 // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
 if( bResults )
 {
 do  
 {
 // Check for available data.
 dwSize = 0;
 if( !WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize ) )
 printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
 GetLastError( ) );

 // Allocate space for the buffer.
 pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize+1];
 if( !pszOutBuffer )
 {
 printf( "Out of memory\n" );
 dwSize=0;
 }
 else
 {
 // Read the data.
 ZeroMemory( pszOutBuffer, dwSize+1 );

 if( !WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,  
 dwSize, &dwDownloaded ) )
 printf( "Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError( ) );
 else
 printf( "%s", pszOutBuffer );

 // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
 delete [] pszOutBuffer;
 }
 } while( dwSize > 0 );
 }


 // Report any errors.
 if( !bResults )
 printf( "Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError( ) );

 // Close any open handles.
 if( hRequest ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hRequest );
 if( hConnect ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hConnect );
 if( hSession ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hSession );
```

can someone give me an idea why this only works with microsoft.com? and how would i go about fixing it?

Comment: adding what those error codes mean may be more helpful

Comment: @Waldermort For what it's worth, 12029 is ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT and 12017 is ERROR_WINHTTP_OPERATION_CANCELLED

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I was hoping to encourage the poster to first use google to identify the error, perhaps giving him insight into what his problem might be. On another note, I really wish MS had used enumerations instead of error codes, making them easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting over HTTPS. www.atomic-gaming.info doesn't present a valid SSL certificate, so WinHTTP refuses to connect to it for security reasons (this can be overridden).

www.yahoo.com redirects to HTTP. It doesn't work for you because you call `WinHttpSetOption` incorrectly. Make it

```
DWORD opt = WINHTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT_POLICY_ALWAYS;
WinHttpSetOption(hSession, WINHTTP_OPTION_REDIRECT_POLICY, &opt, sizeof(opt));
```

Comment: Im getting error 12029 with some sites and 12175 with http://atomic-gaming.info/... whats the problem now?

Comment: and how would i override the ssl certificate verifacation.

Comment: 12175 would be ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE. [Look it up.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383770.aspx) You disable certificate checking by using WinHttpSetOption to set WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS option to a [desired combination of flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066.aspx)

Comment: Im getting 12002,,,, Timeout issue. No idea whats wrong sense the site still works. And with my other domain i tried all the methods and continued to get 12029

Comment: i tried using the options. none of them in combination seem to work. The site loads fine on my web browser its just the connection...

Comment: Your code, with my previously suggested correction, works for the site www.atomic-gaming.info once I add these two lines:
  `opt = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID;`
  `WinHttpSetOption(hSession, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &opt, sizeof(opt));`

Comment: Okay it works with www.atomic-gaming.info but now with www.lystic.info its not working... error 12029

Comment: www.lystic.info doesn't support HTTPS. The server simply doesn't listen on port 443, so of course you can't connect to it.

Comment: To switch to HTTP, you need to change two places in your code: the third parameter to `WinHttpConnect`, and the last parameter to `WinHttpOpenRequest`. Did you update both?

Comment: I feel  stupid. That worked but now im getting an error with www.lystic.info/dbcon.php its error 12005 - ERROR_WINHTTP_INVALID_URL

Comment: Do you specify this as a single string, by any chance? "www.lystic.info" should go into `WinHttpConnect`, while "/dbcon.php" should go into `WinHttpOpenRequest`, as a second parameter.